# Scala wait Await.result for Future.sequence, which futures did not complete on time?

Tags: scala, future

I have list of futures and Await

```scala
val listWithResult = Await.result(Future.sequence(listOfFutures), 10.minutes)
```

It fails with

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10 minutes]
```

- Is there any technique to figure out which future did not complete on time?
- Its there any way to attribute such future with extra metadata to give a clue why it did not complete on time?

Each future submits task and polls polls external service for result. I would like to show that task in stacktrace somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can figure out what didn't complete fairly easily with something like `listOfFutures.filterNot(_.isCompleted)`.

(also, keep in mind, that `Await` is code smell and in vast majority of cases, really not what you want to do).

As to "why", I don't think there is any universal advice here, aside for the usual: logging, metrics, tracing ..

Comment: so wrap val listWithResult = Await.result(Future.sequence(listOfFutures), 10.minutes)
 into try catch TimeoutException and then filterNot isCompleted, did I get it right?